# How to bind a usercontrol property to Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I am having an issue with using a Listbox in my parent project to display a property defined in a user control. To be more specific, I have created a user control which contains a webbrowsercontrol, and I have defined a property called History which contains the history of urls visited during a browsing session. I also have a parent project, which is linked to this user control, in which I am attempting to bind the History property to a Listbox. The point is for someone to be able to see the history urls in a Listbox defined in this parent project, where the history urls are populated by binding to the user control's History property.

Below is my code outlining what I am trying to do:

User Control FullWebBrowser.xaml.cs

```
public partial class FullWebBrowser : UserControl
{
    //ctr
    public FullWebBrowser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //for FullWebBrowser.xaml ContentGrid 
        ContentGrid.DataContext = this;            
    }

    #region Fields

    //The navigation urls of the browser.
    private readonly Stack<Uri> _NavigatingUrls = new Stack<Uri>();

    //The history for the browser
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _History = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the History property for the browser.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<string> History
    {
        get { return _History; }

    }
```

The _NavigatingUrls stack is for the forward and back button implementation, which is working fine, and the _History observablecollection contains the urls from the webbrowsing session shown as follows

```
//If the navigated uri is not in thehistory, add it
            if (!_History.Contains(e.Uri.ToString()))
                _History.Add(e.Uri.ToString());
```

These seem to be working properly, as I have implemented the forward and back buttons and they work ok. The issue is that I cannot properly bind the History property defined in the FullWebBrowser.xaml.cs to my parent project which contains a Listbox. This is shown as follows

HistoryPage.xaml

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:FullBrowserControl;assembly=FullBrowserControl">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Title="QUEST">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="today">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="week">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item three-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="all">
            <StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer>

                    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                     SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=History}" Height="Auto"/>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"
                                       Text="{Binding Modified, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"
                                       Margin="24,0,0,12"/>


                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

                </Scrollviewer>
            </StackPanel>

            <!--<Grid/>-->
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Note, the dateconverter is ok. Here I am trying to implement a Listbox which shows the url with a timestamp below it.
The code behind for this parent project page is as follows

Historypage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class HistoryPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    //Temporary State
    public static readonly Setting<int> CurrentHistoryIndex = new Setting<int>("CurrentHistoryIndex", -1);

    private FullWebBrowser browser = new FullWebBrowser();

    public HistoryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //create new instance of FullWebBrowser user control?
        this.browser = new FullWebBrowser();
        this.DataContext = browser;
        //browser.DataContext = this;
        //this.DataContext = browser.History;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        //Clear the selection so selecting the same item twice in a row will still raise the SelectedChanged event
        CurrentHistoryIndex.Value = -1;
        this.ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            //navigate to the page containing the user control for the selected item
            //how to navigate to Mainpage.xaml and load webbrowsercontrol with selected url??
            CurrentHistoryIndex.Value = ListBox.SelectedIndex;
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my basic implementation. No matter what I try I cannot get the Listbox in Historypage to bind to the History property in the FullWebBrowser user control contained outside of the project, I have referenced the FullWebBrowser control using the references option in the solution explorer, in a using declaration at the top of Historypage.xaml.cs, and by an xmlns statement at the top of HistoryPage.xaml

Any assistance with how this may be accomplished would be greatly appreciated! I have been working on this for a couple weeks and cannot find the solution anywhere, even prowling other's posts. I must implement this solution ASAP! thanks for all your help in advance. Please include code to accomplish this, it would help so much to see how this is implemented for future reference!

Comment: Check the Output window when you run it, do you see some Binding Errors?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` of Your `ListBox` is `FullWebBrowser`, therefore your binding should be as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=History}"/>
```

To solve this kind of problem yourself try debugging, breakpoint your code then inspect the `DataContext` properties of the various elements in your UI.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! Paul, I do not see any databinding errors, and Colin, I have set my binding as you have suggested, but the Listbox is still not populating with the History urls. What would be the correct format for setting DataContext of Listbox to FullWebBrowser. For the HistoryPage.xaml.cs, I created a new instance of the FullWebBrowser as follows because all of my research has indicated that this is necessaary to update the Listbox as new pages are navigated to in the UserControl
'private FullWebBrowser browser = new FullWebBrowser();'
What is the correct databinding code?

Comment: I know that it is common to bind an ObservableCollection to a Listbox, this is standard, but when binding a user control that is outside of the parent project to a Listbox in the parent project, is there something I am missing? I have referenced the outside usercontrol so I have not detected errors when attempting to bind the datacontext, but it is simply not populating the History property urls from the user control to the parent project's Listbox.